# "Sieh einer an": warum kein Akkusativ?

Tags: grammar

Der Übersetzer einer Kurzgeschichte von John O'Hara, *Do You like It Here*, schreibt: "Sieh einer an: ein bisschen Geographie als Dreingabe, wie, Roberts?", ein Satz den ein Lehrer sarkastisch an einen Schüler richtet.
Warum steht *einer* nicht im Akkusativ, sondern, scheint es mir, im Nominativ?

Comment: Als ergänzender praktischer Hinweis zu den exzellenten Antworten: `Sieh einer an!` wird häufig gebraucht und von jedem deutschen als Ausdruck (milden?) Erstaunens verstanden. Du kannst es austauschbar mit dem Ausruf `Interessant!` verwenden. Es ist meiner Meinung nach ganz leicht altmodisch und bildungsbürgerlich.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mit "sieh einer an" ist nicht gemeint, dass *jemand Bestimmtes angesehen* werden soll, wie es der Akkusativ anzeigen würde. Es ist vielmehr die stark eingekochte Version von "Es möge sich jemand diese Sache/Situation ansehen, um dann mit mir übereinzustimmen, wie sonderbar sie ist." Verwandt ist es also eher mit "da schau her!" als mit "schaut ihn an!".

Comment: Ach, ja: ich hätte nicht daran gedacht, aber deine Erklärung ist sehr überzeugznd und sehr klar. Vielen Dank, Jan!

Answer (score 13):

Grammatikalisch handelt es sich bei diesem Konstrukt um einen Imperativ-Satz mit einem Pronomen in der 3. Person in Subjekt-Position.

Andere Beispiele:

> Steh einer auf!
>   Bring einer die Mutter her!

Auch im Englischen gibt es diese Form, wie aus folgenden Beispielen ersichtlich ist:

> Nobody move!
>   Somebody call the doctor!

Abgesehen davon ist "sieh [mal] [einer] an!" eine feste Wendung und wird umgangssprachlich für "Wer hätte das gedacht!" verwendet – ähnlich wie "[das] sehe [sich] einer an!", das "das ist doch nicht zu glauben, ist ganz erstaunlich!" bedeutet.

Comment: Danke für die sehr genaue Erklärung, splattne, insbesondere für die (von mir) unerwartete Analogie mit dem Englischen. Und ich freue mich, dass sie ganz im Einklang  mit Jans ist.

Comment: +1 für die feste Redewendung.