# What is einer doing here?

Tags: meaning, idiom

Attempting to translate:

> Look at the size of them, will you?

I said:

> Schau sich doch ihre Größe an, ja!

My German friends corrected me with:

> Schau sich doch **einer** ihre Größe an, ja!

What "einer" is, and why it needs to be here, are my questions. The only other reference to this idiom I could find was in Reverso Dictionary under anschauen, where it said

> (da) schau einer an! *(inf)* well I never! *(inf)*

which was not helpful. Please advise.

Comment: In German: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2872

Comment: What does "inf" mean (last citation)?

Comment: @userunknown: seems to be directly quoted from Collins dictionary. While I could not find their list of abbreviations,  I assume „informal“.

Comment: @guidot: So i made it italics and put it in parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sentence misses a subject that *sich* could reflect to. That's why you need *einer*. It's similar to *man*:

> Schau sich einer das an!

> Schau man sich das an!

The difference between those two is subtle. *Sich einer* is less definite and thus, almost sarcastic.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to your friend's and @Janka's translation:

I guess that you actually meant "schau" as the imperative form of "schauen", like in the English version.

In that case, the sentence would just need to be:

> Schau *dir* doch ihre Größe an, ja?

If you set a reflexive verb (*"sich etwas anschauen"*) into the imperative form, the reflexive pronoun "sich" becomes "dir", like in the second person singular (*"du schaust dir etwas an"*).

With "Sie", it would be:

> Schauen Sie sich doch ihre Größe an, ja?